# "Unable to parse bindings." when trying to use components using a tag

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a Knockout.js component to reuse but when I load the html page I see the following error in console "Unable to parse bindings"

```css
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var loginComponentViewModel = function(params){
      this.UserName = params.UserName;
      this.Password = params.Password
  }
  ko.components.register('login-component',{
      viewModel: loginComponentViewModel,
   template:{element:'login-templ'}
  })
  ko.applyBindings();
 </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src='knockout-3.4.2.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-bind="component:{
      name: 'login-component',
      params: {UserName:'U1',Password:'1234'}
         }"></div>
    <login-component params="UserName:'U2',Password:'4321"></login-component>
 <template id='login-templ'>
  UserName <input type="text" name="txtUserName" data-bind="value:UserName"><br>
  Password <input type="text" name="txtPassword" data-bind="value:Password"><br>
 </template>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very minor mistake. Exchange the use of double and single quotes when you are using the component.

Instead of `"UserName:'U2',Password:'4321'"`, you have to use `'UserName:"U2",Password:"4321"'`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="component:{
      name: 'login-component',
      params: {UserName:'U1',Password:'1234'}
         }"></div>
    <login-component params='UserName:"U2",Password:"4321"'></login-component>
 <template id='login-templ'>
  UserName <input type="text" name="txtUserName" data-bind="value:UserName"><br>
  Password <input type="text" name="txtPassword" data-bind="value:Password"><br>
 </template>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var loginComponentViewModel = function(params){
      this.UserName = params.UserName;
      this.Password = params.Password
  }
  ko.components.register('login-component',{
      viewModel: loginComponentViewModel,
   template:{element:'login-templ'}
  })
  ko.applyBindings();
 </script>
```